# WPF Image Tooltip

Tags: wpf, image, tooltip, string-formatting

I have a tooltip on an image inside of a listbox. The tooltip is setup as follows:

```
<Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding PingRankImage}" 
        Width="16" Height="16"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="{Binding Ping, StringFormat='Ping: {0}ms'}"
                    ContentStringFormat="{}Ping: {0}ms}" />
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

but the tooltip just displays the value and not the 'Ping: XXXms'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need extra `{}` prefix in `ContentStringFormat`. With `ToolTip`, also prefer using `ContentStringFormat` instead of `StringFormat` in binding.

Following works:

```
<Image.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip Content="{Binding}"
                ContentStringFormat="Ping: {0}ms" />
</Image.ToolTip>
```