# How can I create a complex tooltip in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, tooltip

I have an `Image` control on my WPF Window and I'd like to display a complex tooltip when the mouse is hovering over this Image.

Imagine like a spell icon in World of Warcraft, you mouse over and the spells tooltip is shown.

How can I do this in XAML?

Comment: possibly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847734/wpf-image-tooltip it is also unclear what your question is, you ask about the tooltip on your image, or how to make a complex tooltip?

Comment: @x0r: It's pretty obvious it's both. Creating and complex tooltip and attaching it to mouse over on the spell image.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it like this:

```
<Image>
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip.Content>
            <!--...content goes here. -->
        </ToolTip.Content>
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

Comment: I can't seem to access `ToolTip.Content` I'm using .NET 3.5, is this a 4.0 only property?

Answer (score 1):

You just put whatever you want into the [`ToolTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tooltip.aspx) property in XML element syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing the following to what x0r stated:

```
<Image ToolTipService.ShowDuration="1440000">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip.Content>
            <!--...content goes here. -->
        </ToolTip.Content>
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

This leaves the tooltip open for 24 hours (yes, it's a long time). This is just a way to override that annoying 5-second rule.